# How to achieve this Layout

Tags: android-layout, android-studio-3.0

Hey there I have been wanting to implement a layout that is responsive and scaleable. I have been looking into the Linear Layout with the layout_weight attribute but to no success.

**[Could you give me a hint or point me in the right direction as one would achieve a responsive layout similar to this one in the picture?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7U3XJ.png)**

Answer (score 0):

After some intense search I found this can be achieve by a couple of ways. Either by using `GridLayout` or `GridView` or by just manipulating `LinearLayout` with elements inside it.